# How to clear default select clause on IQueryable resultset

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a page class that returns an IQueryable result set like:

```
protected virtual IQueryable<EntityResult> GetEntities(ETBDataContext pContext)
    {
        return from e in pContext.Entities
               where e.SectionId == SectionId && e.StatusCode == "Published"
               orderby e.PublishDate descending
               select new EntityResult
               {
                   EntityId = e.Id,
                   Excerpt = e.Excerpt,
                   Name = e.Name,
                   PublishDate = e.PublishDate,
                   ShortDescription = e.ShortDescription
               };
    }
```

If I call this method in a inherited class, How can I clear the select and just get the ShortDescription?

```
public void IQueryable<EntityResult> GetResult(ETBDataContext pContext)
{
    IQueryable<EntityResult> pQuery = base.GetEntities(pContext);

    //right here: how can I just return the ShortDescription Only?

    return pQuery;
}
```

I am using the default GetEntities() to do the standard select operation for default queries, but on some calls I would like to get just the specific data that I need.

Is this possible? are there other ways? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
pQuery = pQuery.Select(e => new EntityResult { 
    ShortDescription = e.ShortDescription 
});
```

I'm pretty sure that this won't select the other columns.

Comment: I tried that and the Expression still shows the other columns:

Comment: What do you mean by "shows"?  You cannot change the return type of an overridden function.

Comment: It still gives me Convert(value(System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[ETB.Entity])).MergeAs(AppendOnly).Where(e => ((e.SectionId == value(ASP.rvs_aspx).SectionId) AndAlso (e.StatusCode == "Published"))).OrderByDescending(e => e.PublishDate).Select(e => new EntityResult() {EntityId = e.Id, Excerpt = e.Excerpt, Name = e.Name, PublishDate = e.PublishDate, ShortDescription = e.ShortDescription, }).Select(r => new <>f__AnonymousType0`1(ShortDescription = r.ShortDescription))  as the expression

Comment: @oledu.com: I suspect that EF will ignore the extra columns.

Comment: Yes, but I can return another result set based on EntityResult

Comment: @oledu.com: And therefore what?

Comment: Interesting, so even though it is in the Expression.ToString(), only the data I need will be selected at the datasource level?

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer is correct. I had tried your answer in the past, but the fact that the other columns still showed up in the query expression is what was throwing me off.